# How do I delete the spacing for the equation below?

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I delete the spacing between $\lambda_{A}$ and the parenthesis in the equation below?

$$\lambda_{A}\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=s}^{t} S_i\right)$$

Comment: You could try putting \! between the two.

Comment: I really don't see a problem in the formatting you display in your question.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do it is to use `\mathop` to make $\rm\LaTeX$ think that this is an operator:

$$\mathop{\lambda_A}\left(\bigcup_{i=s}^t S_i\right)\\\lambda_A\left(\bigcup_{i=s}^tS_i\right)$$

(There are also `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` for binary operators and relations respectively.)

Answer (score 3):

As @GerryMyerson mentions in the comments, you can use the [negative space command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9091/117218) `\!`. You can even apply multiple of them if one doesn't have enough effect; the equations below have 0 up to 3 `\!` instances.

$$\lambda_{A}\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=s}^{t} S_i\right)$$
$$\lambda_{A}\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=s}^{t} S_i\right)$$
$$\lambda_{A}\!\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=s}^{t} S_i\right)$$
$$\lambda_{A}\!\!\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=s}^{t} S_i\right)$$

It's even possible to apply so many negative spaces that $\lambda_A$ ends up at the *right* side of the equation:

$$\lambda_{A}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=s}^{t} S_i\right)$$

(but of course there is a much easier way to do so).